# Teamcity - How to make a commit trigger multiple maven profile builds

Tags: maven, teamcity

I am new with TeamCity configuration and I am struggling with doing this (I think) simple thing. Right now I have the following flow working:

1. Someone commits to develop branch
2. TeamCity starts the building proccess:

   1. Check if it was triggered by Git, and if so, sets the default  "dev" profile to build with Maven
   2. Execute the build steps (clean, package, etc...)

The problem is that now we have more than one environment to deploy our application, so when one commits to develop I would like to automatically build for both profiles (lets say dev and prd, for example). How would I do that? 
How would I make a commit to trigger multiple builds?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about teamcity, however if you want to use two profiles, you can do `mvn install -Pprod -Pdev`  (adapt the phase as needed)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like adding another build step for the configuration that already builds  the app